# Alter Table Error:150

Tags: mysql, sql

I cant alter the table to make add a foreign key. Error: 150 comes up. Can't figure out what is wrong. Please assist

```
CREATE TABLE Staff (staffNo varchar(10) NOT NULL, Fname varchar(50),
Lname varchar(50), Staff_Adress varchar(100), Salary numeric(65),
JobPosition varchar(15), Sex varchar(1), DateOfBirth date, NIN varchar(25),OffceNo varchar(10),
PRIMARY KEY (staffNo),
CHECK (Sex IN ('M', 'F')));

CREATE TABLE Office (OfficeNo INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL, Address varchar(50) NOT NULL, City varchar (25) NOT NULL,
PhoneNo varchar(10) NOT NULL, ManagerNo varchar(10),
PRIMARY KEY (OfficeNo),
FOREIGN KEY (ManagerNo) references  Staff(staffNo));

alter table Staff
add foreign key (OffceNo) references Office(OfficeNo) on delete set NULL;
```

Comment: Is there a message along with the error code?\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix these issues:

1. Tables have to be using InnoDB
2. Columns have to have exact same data types

Answer (score 0):

your problem is here :

```
   alter table Staff
   add foreign key (OffceNo) references Office(OfficeNo) on delete set NULL;
```

you have to change this in Staff table

```
   OffceNo varchar(10)
```

to

```
 OffceNo INT(10) unsigned
```

Or this in Office table.

```
 OfficeNo INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL
```

to

```
 OfficeNo varchar(10) NOT NULL
```

for they will be same structure and same data types to use foreign keys.

Comment: OOOh.Thanks for some reason I thought I corrected. It works now.